# Kubernetes metrics-server not working with Linkerd

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd, metrics-server

I have a [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) and a horizontal pod autoscaler using this server, running on my cluster.
This works perfectly fine, until i inject linkerd-proxies into the deployments of the namespace where my application is running. Running `kubectl top pod` in that namespace results in a `error: Metrics not available for pod <name>` error. However, nothing appears in the metrics-server pod's logs.
The metrics-server clearly works fine in other namespaces, because top works in every namespace but the meshed one.

At first i thought it could be because the proxies' resource requests/limits weren't set, but after running the injection with them (`kubectl get -n <namespace> deploy -o yaml | linkerd inject - --proxy-cpu-request "10m" --proxy-cpu-limit "1" --proxy-memory-request "64Mi" --proxy-memory-limit "256Mi" | kubectl apply -f -`), the issue stays the same.

Is this a known problem, are there any possible solutions?

PS: I have a [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) running in a different namespace, and this seems to be able to scrape the pod metrics from the meshed pods just fine [image: grafana dashboard image showing prometheus can collect the data]

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The Kubernetes version is 1.22, and the cluster is set up on bare metal.

Comment: Could you provide information how exactly (step by step) can I reproduce your problem? Please provide your yaml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was apparently a bug in the cAdvisor stats provider with the CRI runtime. The linkerd-init containers keep producing metrics after they've terminated, which shouldn't happen. The metrics-server ignores stats from pods that contain containers that report zero values (to avoid reporting invalid metrics, like when a container is restarting, metrics aren't collected yet,...). You can follow up on the [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/103368) here. Solutions seem to be changing to another runtime or using the PodAndContainerStatsFromCRI flag, which will let the internal CRI stats provider be responsible instead of the cAdvisor one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use `kubectl top` on pods that have linkerd injected:

```
:; kubectl top pod -n linkerd --containers
POD                                       NAME             CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
linkerd-destination-5cfbd7468-7l22t       destination      2m           41Mi            
linkerd-destination-5cfbd7468-7l22t       linkerd-proxy    1m           13Mi            
linkerd-destination-5cfbd7468-7l22t       policy           1m           81Mi            
linkerd-destination-5cfbd7468-7l22t       sp-validator     1m           34Mi            
linkerd-identity-fc9bb697-s6dxw           identity         1m           33Mi            
linkerd-identity-fc9bb697-s6dxw           linkerd-proxy    1m           12Mi            
linkerd-proxy-injector-668455b959-rlvkj   linkerd-proxy    1m           13Mi            
linkerd-proxy-injector-668455b959-rlvkj   proxy-injector   1m           40Mi
```

So I don't think there's anything fundamentally incompatible with the Linkerd and the Kubernetes metrics server.

I have noticed that I will sometimes see the errors for the first ~1m after a pod starts, before the metrics server has gotten its initial state for a pod; but these error messages seem a little different than what you reference:

```
:; kubectl rollout restart -n linkerd deployment linkerd-destination 
deployment.apps/linkerd-destination restarted
:; while ! kubectl top pod -n linkerd --containers linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw ; do sleep 10 ; done
Error from server (NotFound): podmetrics.metrics.k8s.io "linkerd/linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw" not found
Error from server (NotFound): podmetrics.metrics.k8s.io "linkerd/linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw" not found
Error from server (NotFound): podmetrics.metrics.k8s.io "linkerd/linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw" not found
Error from server (NotFound): podmetrics.metrics.k8s.io "linkerd/linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw" not found
POD                                    NAME            CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw   destination     1m           25Mi            
linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw   linkerd-proxy   1m           13Mi            
linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw   policy          1m           18Mi            
linkerd-destination-6d974dd4c7-vw7nw   sp-validator    1m           19Mi
```

```
:; kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.23.3
Server Version: v1.21.7+k3s1
```

Comment: It was a bug in the cAdvisor stats provider with the CRI runtime. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/103368) if you'd like to.